# Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties Xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift

I upgraded to Xcode 8 and my app stopped working and I have been able to fix everything but this one error. I have been looking online and I have not found a fix for this error. Any Help would be appreciated.
Here is the code:

```
struct Party {
    let itemRef:FIRDatabaseReference?
    //
    let userID:String!
    let name:String!
    let title:String!
    let body:String!        

    init (userID:String, name:String, title:String = "", body:String) {
        self.userID = userID
        self.name = name
        self.title = title
        self.body = body
        self.itemRef = nil
    }

    init (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) {
        userID = snapshot.key
        itemRef = snapshot.ref

        if let titl = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
            for child in titl{
                let shotKey = snapshot.children.nextObject() as! FIRDataSnapshot
                if let title = child.value as? [String:AnyObject]{
                    let title = title["title"]
                    print(title)
                }
            }
        }else{
            title = "Failed To Display Title"
        }

        if let user = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
            for child in user{
                let shotKey = snapshot.children.nextObject() as! FIRDataSnapshot
                if let name = child.value as? [String:AnyObject]{
                    let name = name["name"]
                    print(name)
                }
            }
        }else{
            name = "Failed To Display Name"
        }

        if let partyBody = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject]{
            for child in partyBody{
                let shotKey = snapshot.children.nextObject() as! FIRDataSnapshot
                if let body = child.value as? [String:AnyObject]{
                    let body = body["body"]
                    print (body)
                }
            }
        }else{
            body = "Failed To Display Time"
        }
    }

    func toAnyObject() -> Any {
        return ["title":title, "name":name, "body":body]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second `init(snapshot:)` function doesn't set the `name`, `title`, and `body` properties under certain conditions.

You have this code for the `title`:

```
if let titl = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
    for child in titl{
        let shotKey = snapshot.children.nextObject() as! FIRDataSnapshot
        if let title = child.value as? [String:AnyObject]{
            let title = title["title"]
            print(title)
        }
    }
}else{
    title = "Failed To Display Title"
}
```

This code only sets the `title` property in the `else` clause. The four references to `title` inside the `if` part are references to local variables named `title`, not the property named `title`. So the compiler complains you never set the `title` property because there is a possible code path where it isn't set.

You have the same issue for `name` and `body`.